# React native Reanimated Conditional Animated View Movement

Tags: react-native, animation, translate, react-native-gesture-handler, react-native-reanimated-v2

I am  really new to [React-native-reanimated](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated). I am trying to create one custom bottom-sheet like this [app](https://res.cloudinary.com/drewzxzgc/image/upload/v1633178122/olssiutcfaweidtqyflk.gif). I am using `PanGestureHandler` from `react-native-gesture-handler` for move the Animated View to go up and down. For `gestureHandler` I am using `useAnimatedGestureHandler` props from `react-native-reanimated`. I want to move the Animated View from start point to middle screen and bottom of screen. This is My Bottom sheet start point [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ljwyj.png), when scroll the card down it should come middle of the screen like this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyDuv.png), again scroll down the card it will come bottom like this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mt0N2.png).

I am having difficulties with the conditional `useAnimatedGestureHandler` **onEnd** movement. Currently I am tracking  **onEnd's** `event.translationY` and make a condition out of it.

**This is how it works currently:**

When the App start, the Animated View is top of the screen, if I move the card scroll to bottom it goes middle of the screen and it does not go down from middle of the screen, I can move it to up from middle of the screen or if I scroll hard to bottom it goes all the way to bottom and if I try scroll the View up it does not go middle, it just goes up to start View.

I am trying to make the condition based screen size but `I don't know how to make it.`

**I shared my code in [expo-snacks](https://snack.expo.dev/@alakdam/pangesture)**

**This is my all code**

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, useWindowDimensions, RefreshControl } from "react-native";
import MapView from "react-native-maps";
import styled from "styled-components";

import {
  PanGestureHandler,
  PanGestureHandlerGestureEvent,
  FlatList,
} from "react-native-gesture-handler";

import Animated, {
  useAnimatedGestureHandler,
  useAnimatedStyle,
  useSharedValue,
  withTiming,
  Easing,
  withSpring,
} from "react-native-reanimated";

const initialRegion = {
  latitudeDelta: 15,
  longitudeDelta: 15,
  latitude: 60.1098678,
  longitude: 24.7385084,
};

const api =
  "http://open-api.myhelsinki.fi/v1/events/?distance_filter=60.1699%2C24.9384%2C10&language_filter=en&limit=50";

export default function App() {
  const { height } = useWindowDimensions();
  const top = useSharedValue(height);
  const [event, setEvent] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const prevTop = useSharedValue(height * 0.5);
  // This is Fetch Data
  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      setLoading(true);
      const response = await fetch(api);
      const data = await response.json();
      setEvent(data.data);
      setLoading(false);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("erro", error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const animatedStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
    return {
      top: top.value * 0.2,
      bottom: 0,
    };
  });

  const gestureHandler = useAnimatedGestureHandler(
    {
      onStart(_, context) {
        context.translateY = top.value;
      },
      onActive(event, context) {
        top.value = context.translateY + event.translationY;
      },
      onEnd(event, _) {
        // THIS IS MY CONDITION OF ANIMATED VIEW
        if (event.translationY > 0 && event.translationY < 400) {
          console.log("middle-top", top.value);
          console.log("middle-height", height);

          top.value = withSpring(height * 2.5, {
            duration: 500,
            easing: Easing.inOut(Easing.ease),
          });
        } else if (event.translationY > 450 && event.translationY < 800) {
          console.log("bottom-top", top.value);
          console.log("bottom-height", height);
          top.value = withSpring(height * 4, {
            duration: 500,
            easing: Easing.inOut(Easing.ease),
          });
        } else if (event.translationY < 0) {
          console.log("start-top", top.value);
          console.log("start-height", height);
          top.value = withSpring(height, {
            duration: 500,
            easing: Easing.inOut(Easing.ease),
          });
        }
      },
    },
    [top]
  );

  return (
    <>
      <MapView style={styles.mapStyle} initialRegion={initialRegion} />
      <PanGestureHandler onGestureEvent={gestureHandler}>
        <Animated.View style={[styles.container, animatedStyle]}>
          <Title>I am scroll sheet</Title>
          <HeroFlatList
            data={event}
            refreshControl={
              <RefreshControl
                enabled={true}
                refreshing={loading}
                onRefresh={fetchData}
              />
            }
            keyExtractor={(_, index) => index.toString()}
            renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
              const image = item?.description.images.map((img) => img.url);
              const startDate = item?.event_dates?.starting_day;
              return (
                <EventContainer key={index}>
                  <EventImage
                    source={{
                      uri:
                        image[0] ||
                        "https://res.cloudinary.com/drewzxzgc/image/upload/v1631085536/zma1beozwbdc8zqwfhdu.jpg",
                    }}
                  />
                  <DescriptionContainer>
                    <Title ellipsizeMode="tail" numberOfLines={1}>
                      {item?.name?.en}
                    </Title>
                    <DescriptionText>
                      {item?.description?.intro || "No description available"}
                    </DescriptionText>
                    <DateText>{startDate}</DateText>
                  </DescriptionContainer>
                </EventContainer>
              );
            }}
          />
        </Animated.View>
      </PanGestureHandler>
    </>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    position: "absolute",
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    top: 0,

    backgroundColor: "white",
    shadowOffset: {
      height: -6,
      width: 0,
    },
    shadowOpacity: 0.1,
    shadowRadius: 5,
    borderTopEndRadius: 15,
    borderTopLeftRadius: 15,
  },
  mapStyle: {
    flex: 1,
  },
});

const HeroFlatList = styled(FlatList).attrs({
  contentContainerStyle: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
})`
  padding: 12px;
`;

const Title = styled.Text`
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  align-self: center;
  padding: 10px;
`;

const DescriptionText = styled.Text`
  font-size: 14px;
  opacity: 0.7;
`;

const DateText = styled.Text`
  font-size: 14px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  color: #0099cc;
`;

const EventImage = styled.Image`
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  border-radius: 70px;
  margin-right: 20px;
`;

const DescriptionContainer = styled.View`
  width: 200px;
`;

const EventContainer = styled(Animated.View)`
  flex-direction: row;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  shadow-color: #000;
  shadow-opacity: 0.3;
  shadow-radius: 20px;
  shadow-offset: 0 10px;
`;
```

### Tech information

| Tech | Version |
| --- | --- |
| react-native-gesture-handler | ^1.10.3 |
| react-native-reanimated | ^2.2.0 |

Answer (score 1):

Not the perfect solution...
added a new sharedValue to track if its moving up or down.

```
const prevTop = useSharedValue(height * 0.5);
```

and respective code on gesture end.

```
      onEnd() {
        if (top.value > prevTop.value) {
          top.value = withTiming(height * 0.98);
        } else {
          top.value = withTiming(Math.min(200, top.value));
        }
        prevTop.value = top.value;
      },
```

Still there is a scope of improvement.

Comment: Unfortunately, IT'S not a good solution.